# Is there a heatmap solution that works behind a login redirect?

Tags: data-analysis, analytics, qualitative-analysis, single-sign-on, heatmaps

I've been looking for a heatmap to collect analytics on user clicks and behavior; however, I haven't found one that reliably works behind a login redirect. Surely something exists.

I've tried:

- Google Analytics
- ClickTale (trial)
- Clicky (was the closest to working)
- CrazyEgg

We use a Single Sign-on across all of our sites, so it's a common issue for us. Can anybody recommend a solution?

Comment: I thought ClickTale did, but maybe not the trial version?

Comment: While ClickTale __should__ work I wasn't able to confirm, because the trial won't work with HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

I work for an enterprise analytics company and have similar issues with security.

Unfortunately I have not found a pretty heatmap *out of the box* per se, but I have looked into [Piwik](http://piwik.org/). I cannot use it for myself but it looks very interesting and has an [overlay](http://piwik.org/docs/page-overlay/) feature that can be used to create a heatmap. It is installed locally so (I am assuming) it doesn't need outside resources to get around the security issue.

Let me know if it works out for you or if you end up finding something that works.

Comment: Thank you. That looks interesting. I know several people Piwik Pro lists as a client, so I should be able to get some good feedback from them.

Comment: Had a chance to look at a running setup of Piwik Pro, and its heatmap solution was quite lacking. Also happened to get an invite to HotJar beta today, and while I really like its heatmap, they're unable to get a screenshot past the login, thus making the collected data rather useless.

Answer (score 1):

Clicktale [works with https](http://www.clicktale.com/support/faq#t1n242) (expand second question) but definitely not the trial version.  Another one to add to the list is [Mouseflow](http://mouseflow.com/pricing/) which also has https/ssl support but only for paid versions (see the chart at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 1):

[Mouseflow](http://mouseflow.com) can create heatmaps for pages behind a login with no problems. As a previous commenter noted, that feature isn't available on the free plan - but if you contact their support they'll give you a free trial to test it out.

Disclaimer: I work for Mouseflow